# Use queries in a kanban board's columns instead of status

Tags: jira, board

Is there a way in Jira (using an app or not) to categorize my columns based on queries? The swimlanes already support that, but the columns seem to be tied to status. Can I have a matrix that's based on queries in both dimensions?

Comment: Columns are status-based, as the status indicates, well... the status. The whole Kanban theory is based on visualisation of flow across statuses. You may be trying to solve the wrong problem (maybe gathering different projects with different statuses on a consolidated view?). Explain why you want to use formulas on columns and you might have better, more insightful answers.

Answer (score 1):

If you use JIRA Cloud, you can categorize the cards based on colors.

Go to your Kanban board and click on the board settings.

You should see a option for Card colors.

It will let you assign colors to your card based on Queries.

[image]